# Android Listview Item not drawn after setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) is called

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a list view
each row in the list view has height of 450dp for an example
so in most cases, the listview will render at MOST 3 items at the time.

when list view is initially loaded, each row is just an image with a button that says "show details" (all contained in a relative layout)
when user clicks on the button, it hide the current relative layout that has an image and a button by calling setVisibility(View.GONE), and make another view (LinearLayout) shown by calling setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Remember BOTH relative layout and Linear Layout reside in the same xml that was inflated in Adapter.getView(), i am just toggle one of the other in terms of the visibility.

the issue is that, after calling setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) is called on the linear layout, it doesn't show.  It did successfully hide the relative layout, but the linearly layout did not appear.

**It only appears AFTER a new item in the list view needs to be rendered** by scrolling the list view up and down.

how can i force the relative layout to get shown? by force redrawing? i tried that by calling invalidate, it did not work.

i also tried requestLayout, but again, no use.

i also tried notifyDataSetChanged(), it did not work, and i don't think i should call it anyway, because nothing in the data in the adapter has changed, i am simple hiding and showing a new view.

please help

edit:
based on butcode's help, but did not work

```
for(int i=start, j=list.getLastVisiblePosition();i<=j;i++) {
   if(list.getItemAtPosition(vh.position)==list.getItemAtPosition(i)){
       final View view = list.getChildAt(i-start);
       final int index = i;
       view.requestLayout();
       lv.invalidateChild(view, new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom()));
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
                 public void run(){
                     //lv.invalidateChild(view, new Rect(view.getLeft(),
                      //view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom()));     
                     lv.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(view, new Rect(view.getLeft(), 
                           view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom()), false);
                     view.requestLayout();
                     list.getAdapter().getView(index, view, list);
        } 
     });
     break; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChange() method onclick of your button?

Answer (score 0):

system hanler the listview very effectlly, when a item is going to can't see, and anthrod item  will be display, system will reuse the old item instence . if you set the item content view to View.GONE, when you get the item instance ,it's content view's state is View.Gone yet, so you must manually chang the item 's content to View.VISIBLE

Comment: your answer does not help, and i do not understand what you are trying to say.  i am already manually setting the visibility of the item to visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the requestChildRectangleOnScreen(), like this.
Here is My Whole code: a Little different situation is: I will not hide the original layout. But the show/hide the sub layout worked well. Maybe you can referent it.

```
        @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        if (mResultView == null) {
            return;
        }

        View buttonLayout = mResultView.findViewById(R.id.call_button);
        if (buttonLayout == null) {
            return;
        }

        switch (buttonLayout.getVisibility()) {
            case View.GONE:
                for (View view : mVisibleCallButtons) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                mVisibleCallButtons.clear();
                displayCallButton(buttonLayout, true);
                mVisiblePosition = mPosition;
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mListView != null && mResultView != null) {
                            mListView.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(mResultView, new Rect(0, 0,
                                    mResultView.getWidth(), mResultView.getHeight()), false);
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
            case View.VISIBLE:
            default:
                displayCallButton(buttonLayout, false);
                mVisiblePosition = -1;
                break;
        }
    }
};

    private void displayCallButton(View btnLayout, boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        btnLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mVisibleCallButtons.add(btnLayout);
    } else {
        btnLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisibleCallButtons.remove(btnLayout);
    }
}
```

Here is item layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/secondary_action_button"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actions_view_container"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/quickcontact_list_item_padding_bottom" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/call_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <include layout="@layout/call_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, that did not work, i have updated my original question to show the snippet i wrote based on ur suggestion.

Comment: mResultView is the parent view of your relativelayout and linearlayout, In my exmaple,it is created with layout file I provided.